# Identifying maternal grandfather using DNA

Tags: dna, gedcom, family-tree, gramps, gedmatch.com

I have recently started the process of grouping my DNA matches on my mother’s side. It's starting to look like the man I thought was my grandfather may not be. I don't have my mother’s DNA but I have my 1st cousin once removed and her son.

My believed to be grandfather comes from a very popular family and his ancestry goes way back to the 1600's and yet no matches. I find it hard to believe that someone in that line wouldn't show up. Also there are second and beyond cousins that really don't fit in the scheme of things.
I have uploaded my gedcom to gedmatch and I am trying to grasp a way of finding him through there.

How can I go about solving this puzzle?

Comment: We have no way of assessing the plausibility of no matches to your maternal GF's line until we understand where you've tested and what parts of the world that line comes from.